# Cannot successfully connect external hard drive to vmplayer

Tags: external-hard-drive, vmware-player

I'm unable to connect my external hard drive to VMPlayer/virtual machine. The external drive does appear in the list of "Removable Devices" on VMPlayer but when I attempt to connect it issues this error message... "Connection of the USB device was unsuccessful."

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=774) VMware KB article talks about the issue you are experiencing. Some information that would be helpful would be the following. This information is all assuming that you are having issues with "VMware Player" and not "VMPlayer". I'm pretty sure you actually mean "VMware Player". Please reviese your questions and title if you mean "VMware Player".

- VMware Player version
- External USB hard drive manufacturer and model information
- Which operating system is on the virtual machine

As a side note, it appears that a lot of USB 3.0 devices have issues similar to this.